# Javascript what's up with the math?

Tags: javascript

So on my site, I choose items. Prices example are:

```
0.24$, $0.16, $0.15, $0.03
```

If you put all together you get $0.58. Okay, great! Now, I am doing same on my JavaScript and then showing that number with "commas" so it looks nicer, but I am getting something like this: $0.5,800,000,000,000,001.. Why is that happening?

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Comment: Related: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) Note that JavaScript number values are 64-bit floating point.

Comment: Try `return x.toFixed(2).replace(...)` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed))

Comment: Didn't worked. Thanks though